# Sencha build app native error in version 4.0.2.67 for android

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67. Want to build apk for **android** only. Have gone through google and different sencha forum but nothing helps. Please see the bellow image for error message.
[image]

Please help me to build sencha app.

Thank You.

Comment: How does js-impl.xml look like ? What is on line 11 ?

Comment: `8 <x-load-app-builder-properties 
9            refid="${compiler.ref.id}" 
10            splitModePropName="enable.split.mode" 
11            pageModePropName="app.page.mode"/>`

Comment: Ok. now i used sencha cmd v5 and i have successfully build the app using phonegap, by the following command.